# mysql binary logs, specifying the database for each command

Tags: mysql, logging

I am looking to write a backup / restore script based on MYSQL's binary logging.

I have a database on a mysql server, and my colleague also has his own database on the same mysql server.

Looking at the binary logs, I see the statements are logged for both these databases. 
Is the database being written to specified in the logs?

Can I safely replay a binary log containing an extra database in it - i.e. I want to replicate database_A, my binary log file contains commands sent to database_A as well as database_B, can I replay these commands into a copy of database_A safely? Or do I need to ask my sysadmin to only log things for dataabse_A?

Answer (score 0):

OK, studying the log files a bit more, it seems that the mysql binlog utility adds the "use database" statements in the appropriate place. I added a part to my script that effectively grepped out the relevant database statements.